Discretionary income
I want to know where I could find a statistic related to the discretionary income by country in relation to the purchasing power and median salary of the respective country. From what I have researched, discretionary income refers to the money left over after an individual has paid all their taxes, rent, grocery spendings and other necessary spendings of the sorts. I am interested in such a statistic because I consider moving to another country and think such statistics prove useful. My main point of interest for this statistic would be countries in Europe.

I'm not sure this question is relevant to this site, but perhaps you can find what you need at https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/comparison.jsp.

All askers have a personal interest in knowing the answers, so I would say it is relevant. However "discretionary income" is very ill-defined, since groceries can include any level of luxury (Do you really need sauce on pasta? And truffles?). How about rewriting the question about disposable income? Then you can substract cost of living according to your living standards.
